# Upload self-signed ssl certificate to telegram

Tags: php, ssl, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm making telegram bot using webhook on php. The problem is that the webhook doesn't set correctly and idk whats the matter.
my setwebhook code :

```
$ch = curl_init(API_URL);
try {
    $cert = new \CURLFile(SSL_KEY);
apiRequest('setWebhook', array('url' =>  WEBHOOK_URL , 'certificate' => $cert));
    echo "webhook set";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the exact error that you get from Telegram Servers.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the webhook via the terminal rather than in your code like so:

```
curl -F "url=https://your_domain.com/where-the-script-will-be/bot-script.php" -F "certificate=@/location/of/cert/certificate.crt" https://api.telegram.org/bot000000000:AAAAa0aAA_aaA-Aaaa0A0Aa_a0aa0A0AAAA/setWebhook
```

This has worked for my own projects without any issues