# Set web hook for python telegram bots

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm writing a telegram bot by python and telepot package.I want to set web hook on my bot.please help me how can i set web hook on this bot?

Comment: Nowhere you can find a better guidance rather than telegram itself: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks

Comment: yes, but i didn't understand anythings :(

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554548/how-to-set-telegram-bot-webhook/42556264#42556264

Comment: thank you, in item 5 :Upload your certificate file.what is certificate file?

Comment: where can i find certificate file?I have ssl certificate on my site.