# Telegram Bot API - Webhook

Tags: c#, ssl, google-compute-engine, telegram, telegram-webhook

I'm trying to set a webhook for my inline bot.

The server is hosted by Google Compute Engine, running Windows Server 2016, IIS 10, is bound to a domain and have a self-signed certificate (I think that's the part that is blocking me)

I created a Web API in C# and tested it with Postman.

I've checked out [this Telegram page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#a-self-signed-certificate) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556264/5901111), but I'm still having problems.

Return of `https://api.telegram.org/botXXX/getWebhookInfo`:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result":
    {
        "url": "https://myserver.url:443/path/to/api",
        "has_custom_certificate": true,
        "pending_update_count": 41,
        "last_error_date": 1523561516,
        "last_error_message": "SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
        "max_connections": 100
    }
}
```

Comment: self signed certificate won't work. Try to get one from letsencrypt/

Comment: Read the Telegram page. It says I can