# Where should I configure webhook url to get the latest user send message from bot added telegram group

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, webhooks

I have read some documents to understand the webhook configuration for getting the latest user send messages from bot added telegram group the documents and the links are [this](https://hevodata.com/learn/telegram-webhooks/) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554548/how-to-set-telegram-bot-webhook), [this](https://xabaras.medium.com/setting-your-telegram-bot-webhook-the-easy-way-c7577b2d6f72) , [telegram api doc](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/reference/setwebhook) and [telegram bot doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)

I understand the concept but I'm getting the confusion on configuration of webhook url to get the latest messages and where should I configure this webhook url.

Note :- Should configure this webhook url in our server([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))?

Example webhook url is :

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{my_bot_token}/setWebhook?url={url_to_send_updates_to}
```

Suggest me how to work with telegram webhook. And get the latest user send messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Webhook on your own static web address, for instance:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/setWebhook?url=https://www.example.com
```

There should be POST-handler on this route, that way Telegram's updates can be received.

Comment: Hi @rykov7 I have added how you given the solution and the  webhook is hitting every time when the user send the message in telegram bot added group but I'm not able to getting the User info I'm getting this error `{"ok":false,"error_code":429,"description":"Too Many Requests: retry after 1","parameters":{"retry_after":1}}` where I did the mistake can you suggest me ?

Answer (score 0):

You must set your webhook manually.
You've got a `bot_token` and you know which url will receive the POST updates `webhook_url`

You run this link in your browser with your configuration:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/setWebhook?url={webhook_url}
```

After that any update will be send to your webhook url as a JSON

If you got an error `429: Too Many Requests`, you must handle this in your code.
It comes because you are sending to many requests to the Bot API, and every bot has a limit `30 request/second`.

So try to minimize requests as much as possible in your code and do some `Thead.Wait()` if needed